# I'm having trouble with this print function on a Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

So for a class, I'm supposed to create a set of flight itineraries using a doubly linked list. The program is supposed to print the outgoing trips then print a list of return trips (i.e. Dallas to Houston then Houston to Dallas). Everything else seems to be in order, but for the past 4 days or so I haven't been able to get my print function to work, I can't tell what's going wrong.

```
void list::printList(struct NODE* NODE){  
struct NODE* last;  
cout<<"Flight Records for HowardAir Flight CSCI0136:"<<endl;
while (NODE != NULL) {  
    cout<< NODE->data << " to ";//<< NODE->data<<endl;  
    last = NODE;  
    NODE = NODE->next;  
    cout<<NODE->data<<endl;
}  
cout<<""<<endl; 

cout<<"Reverse Flight Records for HowardAir Flight CSCI0136:"<<endl;  
while (last != NULL) {  
    cout<<last->data<< " to ";  
    last = last->prev;  
    cout<<last->data<<endl; 
}
```

}

Here's what the struct NODE looks like:

```
struct NODE {  
    string data;  
    struct NODE* next;  
    struct NODE* prev;  
};
```

I've heard about some confusion over the "last" variable in my function. The idea behind the "last" variable is that the while loop will just keep going until the program prints the last node on the list. So "last" just means that we were going back to the last/latest node that was printed before. So it's just printing what was just printed in the regular print function but backwards.

You'll notice that I commented out part of the first while loop in the printList function. When it's put back into the code and the last line of that respective while loop is commented out, the first set of itineraries will obviously look like "Dallas to Dallas, Houston to Houston, etc...". That said, if there is a way I could update the variable in the same cout line, this wouldn't be a problem.

I've tried splitting this function into two (one for regular printing and one for reverse printing) and that didn't work either. Does this have something to do with the fact that I'm updating the variable between prints? Or is it something else entirely?

Here's a link to my repl.it if you want to poke at the code more directly: [A link the rest of this code...](https://repl.it/@HannahLeonard1/Computer-Science-II-Flight-Lab)

Comment: first note : while (NODE != NULL) should be NODE->next!=null since you are using the next node inside the while without testing

Comment: Please take a look at [our intro page on minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post complete code, not a link. Without knowing e.g. what a node is supposed to contain, it's hard to advise you, but `cout<< NODE->data << " to " << NODE->data` will definitely give you something that looks like "Dallas to Dallas".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem of method. A double chained list must have the first and the last element pointer in the structure.

```
struct T_Element
{
   previous *T_Element = nullptr;
   next *T_Element     = nullptr;
};

class T_List
{
public:
/*add and delete functions*/
   void print()
   {
       for(T_Element *element = first; element != nullptr ; element = element->next)
       {
          print(element); /*to define*/
       }
   }
   void reversePrint()
   {
      for(T_Element *element = last; element != nullptr ; element = element->previous)
     {
        print(element); /*to define*/
     }
  }
private:
   first *T_Element = nullptr;
   last *T_Element  = nullptr;
};
```